# ACF Change Background Image on Hover

Tags: javascript, wordpress, background-image, dom-events, advanced-custom-fields

Been trying to get a solution for this for a while now and haven't been able to come up with anything that works.

My goal is that when you hover over this particular div, the background image will change to a darkened version of that background image. I've tried using the filter property but it affects all of the inside divs containing content. (Through JavaScript)

This is being done inside a repeater field through ACF. So the background-image is being selected by the sub-field in within the repeater.

I've attempted some Javascript but haven't found a solution.

Also looked at replacing the div's hence you'll see a hover-div. But had no luck.

Below you'll find my code for reference.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

```
<div class="member-wrap grid-x grid-margin-x grid-margin-y">
            <?php if ( have_rows( 'branch_team_members' ) ) : ?>
                <?php while ( have_rows( 'branch_team_members' ) ) : the_row(); ?>
                    <div class="branch-member-main small-12 medium-6 large-3 cell">
                        <?php $team_member_hover_image = get_sub_field( 'team_member_hover_image' ); ?>
                        <div class="main-member-hover" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $team_member_hover_image['url']; ?>');">    
                        </div>
                        <?php $team_member_image = get_sub_field( 'team_member_image' ); ?>
                        <div class="main-member-area" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $team_member_image['url']; ?>');">
                            <h4 class="member-name-hover"><?php the_sub_field( 'team_member_name' ); ?></h4>
                            <span class="member-position-hover"><?php the_sub_field( 'team_member_position' ); ?></span>        
                            <?php the_sub_field( 'team_member_bio' ); ?>
                        </div>
                        <div class="main-member-contact">
                            <span class="member-name"><?php the_sub_field( 'team_member_name' ); ?></span>
                            <span class="member-contact"><?php the_sub_field( 'team_member_contact' ); ?></span>
                        </div>                      
                    </div>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
            <?php else : ?>
                <?php // no rows found ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
```

Comment: Are you getting all expected HTML as output from this spinet? If so, can you add that HTML to this question so I can look at what can be done at the browser?

Comment: It will be hard to online-style a pseudo element like `:hover` - My suggestion here, would be to give a specifik id, according to your rows, and cheate a `<style>` block inside that row as well

Comment: _“I've tried using the filter property but it affects all of the inside divs containing content.”_ - well then change the structure …? Put the background image on its own div element, which you then absolutely position behind the actual content … then you can apply any filters you like, without it affecting the actual contents.

Comment: @ibex All HTML is included in the snippet. You won't be able to see how it looks in the browser with how it is as the fields are relational to my ACF Setup.

Comment: @CBroe I tried doing that then using z-index to order it and still had no change.

Comment: @JLawless I do understand I won't be able to see the output my self when I don't have the same setup locally. This was the reason I asked for the output (pure HTML) of this snippet. [Stender](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51854906/1632961)'s answer seems to be a better solution - having an inline style tag for each team member

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't debugged it all - but this might give you an idea, on how to do it.

This method will create a  block for each box with a counter

```
<div class="member-wrap grid-x grid-margin-x grid-margin-y">
        <?php if ( have_rows( 'branch_team_members' ) ) : ?>
            <?php $counter; ?>
            <?php while ( have_rows( 'branch_team_members' ) ) : the_row(); ?>
                <?php $team_member_hover_image = get_sub_field( 'team_member_hover_image' ); ?>
                <?php $counter++; ?>

                <style type="text/css">
                    .blockNumber-<?php echo $counter; ?>{
                        background-image: url('<?php echo $team_member_image['url']; ?>');
                    }
                    .blockNumber-<?php echo $counter; ?>:hover{
                        background-image: url('<?php echo $team_member_hover_image['url']; ?>');
                    }

                </style>

                <div class="branch-member-main small-12 medium-6 large-3 cell">


                    <?php $team_member_image = get_sub_field( 'team_member_image' ); ?>
                    <div class="main-member-area blockNumber-<?php echo $counter; ?>">
                        <h4 class="member-name-hover"><?php the_sub_field( 'team_member_name' ); ?></h4>
                        <span class="member-position-hover"><?php the_sub_field( 'team_member_position' ); ?></span>        
                        <?php the_sub_field( 'team_member_bio' ); ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="main-member-contact">
                        <span class="member-name"><?php the_sub_field( 'team_member_name' ); ?></span>
                        <span class="member-contact"><?php the_sub_field( 'team_member_contact' ); ?></span>
                    </div>                      
                </div>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php else : ?>
            <?php // no rows found ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I'll have a dive into this soon and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Update: The reason is wasn't grabbing the first background is because it wasn't declared before the style block. Just this small little tweak did it. Thanks!

Comment: No problem - like i said - it gave you the idea, and i hadn't debugged or checked it :) glad that it worked